# NavigationLink in SwiftUI won't accept arguments

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

My NavigationLink does not appear to be working as advertised, in that it is not accepting arguments to display text or a view. My code is as follows:

```
struct MainContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // MARK: PROPERTIES
        
        let mainData: [MainData] =
            Bundle.main.decode("mainData.json")
        
        // MARK: BODY
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Image("hsSampleBack")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                ForEach(mainData) { mainDataPoint in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Selection() {
                            Text("Text Here")
                        })
                }//:LOOP
            } //: LIST
            .navigationBarTitle("Data Points", displayMode: .large)
        } //: NAVIGATION
    }
}
```

I am getting the following 2 error messages over my NavigationLink line:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

If these seems contradictory to you, join the club. On the one hand it claims that no arguments are permitted, and then it's flagging a missing argument. It seems to want to call for a "Label" Text argument, which would be fine, except that I ultimately want to pass a View, which I have done successfully elsewhere.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is corrected syntax

```
    ForEach(mainData) { mainDataPoint in
        NavigationLink(destination: Selection()) {
                Text("Text Here")
            }
    }//:LOOP
```